# Make malloc() return NULL instead of crashing the program?

Tags: c, macos, crash, memory-management, malloc

I am allocating memory in a C program using `malloc`. It's possible for my program to allocate more memory than the system has room for, at which point the program crashes. For my purposes it would be better if `malloc` would just return `NULL` (like it's apparently [supposed to](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malloc#Allocation_failure)), so I can catch the error. Instead what it does is it throws an error saying "No memory available to program now: unsafe to call malloc." And crashes the program.

How can I fix this?

Edit: I know that the program is crashing by itself and not because I'm trying to reference a null pointer. The program never directly calls `malloc`, but instead calls a function I wrote that calls `malloc` and then checks to see if it returns `NULL`. It's never saying that `malloc` returned `NULL`.

Edit 2: If it's helpful, here is the complete error output:

> Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
>   sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
>   warning: Unable to restore previously selected frame.
>   Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'. (The program being debugged was signaled while in a function called from GDB.
>   GDB remains in the frame where the signal was received.
>   To change this behavior use "set unwindonsignal on"
>   Evaluation of the expression containing the function (dlopen) will be abandoned.)
>   No memory available to program now: unsafe to call malloc

Comment: Depends on your OS. Are you on Linux, Mac, Windows?

Comment: Mac OS X Snow Leopard. (I'm not sure if OS version matters, but it can't hurt to know.)

Comment: Could you post the function you are calling malloc in?

Comment: Don't blame the library. Your malloc is probably working fine until a bug in your code scribbled all over the heap which makes malloc sad.

Comment: GWW: It's too long. The relevant part, though, looks like this:  

    ptr = malloc(...);  
    if (ptr == NULL) /* error handling */  
    else return ptr;  

(Edit: Sorry for the formatting, how do I make it indent?)

Comment: @msw: There are systems where `malloc` returns non-NULL even when the memory isn't available.  For example, see the "Bugs" section of the Linux `malloc` man page: http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc

Comment: @jamesdlin: I don't think that's the problem. Accessing the memory isn't what's causing a crash; if `malloc` returned un-allocated memory, that should be causing the program to crash. But it's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you scribble on the heap via buffer overruns, wild pointers or other bugs, malloc's behavior becomes undefined and it could return anything.

Malloc is simply a user-space library; there isn't any magic contained within it. If I scribble all over your application's linked list of customer names, you'll get weird behavior when you later access that list. Malloc behaves in the same way, but since the use of malloc is distributed through the code, cause and effect have global reach.

All of the answers are dancing around the fact that pointer errors are the single most prevalent source of defects in C code. You are lucky you are getting a SIGBUS which is the evidence of defect that may be widely separated from where and when the fault occurs. Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to help you find where the real defect is.

Comment: +1 for valgrind. If `malloc()` is doing impossible things, then it seems likely that you have inadvertently damaged some of the heap.

Comment: Thanks. I will install Valgrind. You make me think that probably what's happening is I'm putting too much stuff into an array and it's going off the end.

Comment: Oops, it looks like Valgrind isn't supported on OS 10.6. Short of installing a different operating system, do you know of any similar programs that work on 10.6?

Comment: Alas, the last time I touched a Mac, OS 8 was the new shiny. You might want to start a new "How to catch C pointer errors on MacOS X.6?" question as questions get stale around here pretty quickly.

Comment: @msw: Malloc may or may not simply be a user-space library.  If a C compiler sees that a function calls `malloc` and later unconditionally calls `free` on the received pointer, it may replace the calls to `malloc` and `free` with code that allocates/releases space on the stack and not bother calling `malloc` at all.

Comment: @supercat I have little doubt that the spec affords that implementation "as if malloc was called"; as does the spec with many other definitions. I'm curious if you've seen it done in the wild as I can think of a dozen ways that it screws with the language semantics. An easy example is overriding my `-lspecial_malloc` linker option since malloc doesn't get resolved until link time and code generation has already completed by then.

Comment: @msw: I've read of compilers eliding `malloc`/`free` calls.  The Standard says nothing about how a C compiler interacts with the underlying platform; although such behavior would contradict the documented behavior of such platforms, in the absence of a platform restriction which would preclude it the Standard itself says nothing that would forbid it.

Answer (score 1):

It checks to see if Malloc returns NULL?   You may have a problem with the equality test.  Try something like  'if (malloc(...)) then ...;  else  ...;' rather than a specific check.

If that fails to help then run just the preprocessor and work out what NULL is being 'edited' to be.

Comment: "if (malloc(...)) then ...; else ..." has the same problem. NULL is edited to (void *)0, which is what you'd expect, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it is, but there could have been a mistaken redeclaration of NULL that made it something else. We know from the standard that non-NULL pointers are "true", so this was a reasonable dead chicken to wave over the problem...

Answer (score 1):

According to [this apple page](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/malloc.3.html), the program will abort based on a malloc error if the `MallocErrorAbort` environment variable is turned on in xcode. To turn off this variable, right-click on the executable in the Tree view, select "Get Info," and go to the "Arguments" tab.

Comment: It originally wasn't there, so I put it in and set it to 0. The problem was not fixed. The problem persists when I compile the program from the command line instead of from Xcode. Also, thanks for the link.

Comment: Then I set MallocErrorAbort to YES and the compiler gave me a message indicating that it was on. The program crashed in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Strange ... the following works for me if I compile it from the command line.  The runtime supplied `malloc` does have [a lot of options as Spencer mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518283/make-malloc-return-null-instead-of-crashing-the-program/3518397#3518397).  If you are using XCode, I would look for an option that controls this.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int
main()
{
    signed long long alloc_sz = (1 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024);
    while (alloc_sz > 0ull) {
        char *ptr = malloc(alloc_sz);
        if (ptr == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "failed to allocate %llu bytes\n",
                    (unsigned long long)alloc_sz);
            break;
        } else {
            free(ptr);
            fprintf(stderr, "allocated %llu bytes\n",
                    (unsigned long long)alloc_sz);
        }
        alloc_sz *= 2ull;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

*BTW:* is this in a *debug* or *release* build?  It may be that XCode is trying to help you out somehow.

Comment: I ran that code, and it gave some output and then `malloc` returned NULL. Now we know that something else is causing the problem. BTW: Debug build.

Answer (score 0):

As the others have said, it's very likely that you have overwritten some of `malloc's` internal state, causing it to do weird things.

On Linux, the way you would track this down would be to use `valgrind`. If your code is sufficiently cross-platform that you can run it on Linux (perhaps in a VM) I would recommend doing this.

If this option is not available to you, Mac OS X has its own built-in debugging tools. At a high level there is Instruments. At lower level, `malloc` will enable debugging in response to certain environment variables:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/malloc.3.html
Scroll down to the `ENVIRONMENT` section. So for example you would run your program with

```
MallocGuardEdges=1 ./myProg
```

You can also use `libgmalloc` which is like the `malloc` debugging features on crack. You can read about it here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/libgmalloc.3.html

You would run your program like this:

```
DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/usr/lib/libgmalloc.dylib ./myProg
```